# Can we open the print dialog box in chrome without opening the pdf itself?

Tags: javascript

my application will run on a modified version of chrome whose default pdf viewer is the "[pdf reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-reader/ieepebpjnkhaiioojkepfniodjmjjihl?hl=en)" extension. I am

- making an Api call and getting data
- creating a blob out of it
- converting the blob into a url
- putting it in an iframe and the calling iframe.contentWindow.print().

On calling this function chrome opens the pdf file in the pdf reader and then displays the pdf reader's print dialog box thereby closing the web application itself. Whereas it should after print it should redirect the user to the home page.

In this modified version of chrome we cannot open a new tab using script or anything. All I need to do is display the print dialog box only.

Is there a way to directly open the print dialog box of chrome or the pdf viewer without opening the pdf document itself. Please find my code below

`

```
function print(blob){
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.setAttribute("src",url);
  iframe.style.position = "absolute"; 
  iframe.style.top = "1px";
  iframe.style.left = "1px";
  iframe.style.height = "-1px";
  iframe.style.weight = "-1px";
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  iframe.contentWindow.print();
```

`

P.S.: I am very new to javascript and html.